# How to effectively filter queries in SQL Profiler?

Tags: sql-server

I use SQL Profiler against our development database to monitor Entity Framework and SharePoint queries.

The problem is that the database is queried heavily by many other developers and applications, and we use the same login info, so I find it hard to find the queries I generate.

I tried to filter the results, but with little luck. Any suggestions? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<connectionStrings>

    <add name="MyConnectionStringName" connectionString="server=.;database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;Pooling=false;Application Name='EasyAsAbc123';" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

</connectionStrings>
```

Now in the profiler, set a filter "By application name" to "EasyAsAbc123".

Comment: Yeah, anywhere where one is hitting the same database with the same credentials..this is a life-saver.  Any code I check in to source control has a a "CHANGE_ME_WHEN_DEPLOYED" default value....  to remind people to change it to something simple and unique.  An over populated profiler will drive you nuts.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to make solid recommendations without knowing more about your environment. Is this a shared database, but with independent development IIS servers hitting it? If so, then you can filter by HostName.